# How to prove the distributive law for propositional logic without using truth tables or natural deduction.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I haven't learnt natural deduction yet so I'm completely stuck on how to proceed. One tip I was given was to use the properties of negation but again, that's not really helping.

Comment: So no truth-table, and no natural deduction?  What *can* you use? Equivalence principles?  But this the well-known equivalence principle of Distribution itself ...

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know. We were given some equivalence principles such as p=>q ≡ ~p ∨q but the hint is throwing me off. Some online sources use things such as p ∨ ~p ≡ T and  p ∧ ~p ≡ C to mean negation principles which is what I've been trying to use.

Comment: Hmm, that's confusing and frustrating indeed.  You must have been given some list of rules though, Indeed, I would not use online resources, because there you'll most lkely find rules that are not on the list you were given (indeed, most resources will simply list Distribution, and now you're done!) Can you post the rules that were given to you?

Comment: I have updated the post with all the rules we have been given.

Comment: Can you assume $\lnot(\lnot P)\equiv P$?

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot that

Answer (score 1):

Use the definitions of the symbols.

---

$(P\wedge Q)\vee R$ means at least one from these cases: $P\wedge Q$ is true, or $R$ is true.

If $P\wedge Q$ is the case, then $P$ and $Q$ are both true.  When $P$ is true, $P$ or $R$ is true; which means $P\vee R$ is true.  Likewise when $Q$ is true, $Q\vee R$ is true. So having both $P$ and $Q$ means $(P\vee R)$ and $(Q\vee R)$ are true. Which means this case entails $(P\vee R)\wedge(Q\vee R)$.

If $R$ is the case, then we have $P$ or $R$; which means $P\vee R$. Likewise this case entails $Q\vee R$. Thus this case also entails $(P\vee R)\wedge(Q\vee R)$.

Therefore $(P\wedge Q)\vee R$  entails $(P\vee R)\wedge(Q\vee R)$.

---

Now show that $(P\vee R)\wedge(Q\vee R)$ entails  $(P\wedge Q)\vee R$ .

Comment: Is that not "natural deduction"?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove this using only the rules as given, and here is why:

Use a classical two-value logic, interpret the $\neg$, $T$, and $C$ as normal, but interpret the $\lor$ as the classical $XOR$, and the $\land$ as the classical $\leftrightarrow$. Finally, define the $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ in accordance with the first and third equivalence principle respectively.

The Double Negation principle holds as normal, so the last equivalence principle holds. The two equivalence principles before that are easily verified as well. Also, since the classical $XOR$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are commutative, the newly interpreted $\lor$ and $\land$ are as well, so that takes care of principles 6 and 7. Then, since the $XOR$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are each other's dual, we have principles 4 and 5. Pricniples 1 and 3 hold by definition, and principle 2 is easily verified. So: with this interppretation, all of your given equivalence hold.

However, Distribution no longer holds, since the $XOR$ does not distribute over the $\leftrightarrow$. So, the Distribution priciple cannot be derived from the given $10$ equivalence principles.

Are you sure you have all of them listed?

Comment: Nice. I just found confusing that you referred to those principles where there are none in the post. Oddly enough, the OP removed them, making the question less complete (or should we say, impossible to answer).

Comment: @amrsa Oh! Yes, that's too bad the OP removed the principles ... I was so pleased I found such a nice meta-proof that it wasn't provable from the ones the OP had listed. Oh well! At least you appreciated it :)

Comment: Yes, I appreciated very much. In fact, I didn't know about this example, which is actually quite simple!